# Reduce recompilation when editing global variables

Tags: c++, compilation, global-variables, constants, game-engine

I am working on a game,
I have a huge list of const global variables .h file which many .cpp file relies on.
(Enemies would like to know the max hp of players etc)

However, this is a compilation nightmare when any variable is changed in the file for game balancing.

I would like to prevent splitting up the files into multiple headers for the ease of the guy in charge of game balancing.

However, recategorizing is kind of a pain (clarity vs compile time, Player's maximum hp is used in many .cpp but it should belong to the PlayerVariables.h, including it in every file that uses it kind of destroys the purpose of splitting them up).

Is there a way to save some time other than the method above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the global variables in the header file. And define them in another source file. That way if any of the values are changed only the globals.cpp needs to be recompiled since everything includes globals from the hpp.

In globals.hpp:

```
extern const unsigned PLAYER_MAX_HEALTH;
```

In globals.cpp:

```
#include "globals.hpp"

const unsigned PLAYER_MAX_HEALTH = 100;
```

Comment: And there goes one of the advantages there were: Compile-time constants and constant-propagation.

Comment: Hey thanks for the recommendation, I did this exactly a while ago with just some minor problems with using them with array sizes and enums, works nicely with just the drawback of typing the names twice haha, I will just wait a while to see what explore the possibilities before marking as answer!

Comment: Any solution to your problem will mean having to define the values of the globals in a source file. It will always be the case that any change made to a header file will mean that all source files that include the header will need to be recompiled. What were the problems you were having with array sizes and enums?

Comment: Nothing much, just the compiler refusing to accept extern constants in array declarations and c style enums (unsigned representations), I just moved them to the places that needed them or kept them without extern (they dun change as frequently).

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a configure-step with the preprocessor:

1. Only have preprocessor `#define`s in the config.h
2. Split it with the preprocessor into multiple headers only pulling in those definitions they need to declare actual const variables / enum-values / whatever.
3. Only copy those files which are different from the previous run over the previous version.
4. Optionally also have a glabals.cpp defining those symbols which might also need a definition.
5. Make sure to (re-)run make after the configuration was updated.

The advantage over just declaring external constant variables and defining and initializing them in a different translation-unit is constant-propagation and having proper compile-time-constants.